# Is there a way to modify reshade to choose presets based on a variable? [SWRC Unreal Engine 2]

Tags: unreal-engine4

I'm currently making a mod for Star Wars Republic Commando that uses reshade, and some presets work for certain levels and not so much for other. So is there a way if I pull out the current level from GameData and Saves file as a variable, could there be a way to modify the Reshade's code to change current preset to the variable? eg. Level - Geonosis01, and the preset changes to "Geonosis01". Thanks

I accessed the Saves file and found the current saved level, it's autosaving every couple minutes and when the level is changed.